# Moving variables up in subsequent Python functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I've been reading some ways to import variables or making them global in different Python modules but I believe my case is a bit more complex. I also tried

> import config

But I didn't manage to get it right

I have a series of functions programmed that have a jerarchy (each function calls the one below and so on).
So far I've managed to retrieve the variables I want through the return statement but as the whole thing grows it gets very dirty and long.
Any ideas of how I could set the variables that I created in one of the functions accesible to all the upper levels?
So I have:
**Level 1)**

```
def t2m(...):
    ...
    L=np.array(l1)
    ret=[...,L,...]
    return ret
```

**Level 2)**

```
ret=twm(...)
L=ret[3]   #3 is an example

def dc(...,L,...):
    ...
    # L is not even used in this level 
    ...
    ret=[...,...,L,...]
    return ret
```

**Level 3)**

```
ret=dc(...)
L=ret[n]
for j in L:
    ...
```

So pretty much I have many L's and even more levels so it's getting terrible. Can I somehow make L accessible from everywhere when I create it?

Thanks!

Comment: You normally use functions to delegate (sub) tasks. If the caller of the 'top' function needs to have the output of those other functions, then you are not delegating anymore, and your top-level code should probably just call those functions *directly* instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Restructure your code such that you have only one level of call nesting
2. Package this up in an object, and store shared values on `self`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm working on this but can't figure out what you mean with self

Comment: @user2685953 Have you ever seen any python classes? The standard name for the first parameter of a method is `self`.